# filtering query results by unique field in ms access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are 150 distinct Address1 values in qrySummaryData.  I want to return several other fields for each of the 150 distinct Address1 values.  However, the query below returns 228 rows, including redundant values for Address1.  Can anyone show me how to fix the query below so that it returns only the 150 rows that I need?

```
SELECT Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, County, PHONE_NUMBER 
FROM qrySummaryData 
WHERE Address1 
IN (SELECT DISTINCT Address1 FROM qrySummaryData);
```

Comment: What happens if you do `SELECT DISTINCT Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, County, PHONE_NUMBER FROM qrySummaryData`?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong by being too complex, with the `IN` clause.  Try what Gord Thompson suggests.  If you get >150 records, then you have to either apply `GROUP BY` to `Address1`, or remove one or more of the other fields.  For example, maybe two records are identical except for the `PHONE_NUMBER`.

If you want to investigate where that variant information is, you can use the query wizard to Find Duplicates.  Of course, you are dealing with few records so in this case you can eyeball it.